# Running background loop on Python

Tags: python, serial-port, listener

I'm trying to make an Python serial port listener application.

My problem is running the listener function on background without killing the GUI.

Here it is the code:

```
import sys
import getopt
import serial
from time import sleep
from threading import *
from Tkinter import *
import io
#ser = serial.serial_for_url('loop://', timeout=1)
#sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))

runing = True
ser = None
class App:
  global ser
  def __init__(self, master):
    varCOM = StringVar(master)
    varCOM.set("COM1")
    listbox = OptionMenu(master, varCOM, "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4")
    listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

    varBaudRate = StringVar(master)
    varBaudRate.set(4800)
    listboxBaudrate = OptionMenu(master, varBaudRate, 300, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 38400)
    listboxBaudrate.grid(row=0, column=1) 

    varParity = StringVar(master)
    varParity.set("None")
    listboxParity = OptionMenu(master, varParity, "None", "Even", "ODD", "Mark", "Space")
    listboxParity.grid(row=1, column=0)

    varDataBits = StringVar(master)
    varDataBits.set(8)
    listboxDataBits = OptionMenu(master, varDataBits, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    listboxDataBits.grid(row=1, column=1)

    varStopBits = StringVar(master)
    varStopBits.set(2)
    listboxStopBits = OptionMenu(master, varStopBits, 1, 2)
    listboxStopBits.grid(row=2, column=0)

  def detener():
    global runing
    runing = False
    detencion = Thread(target=detener)

  def detencionRun():
    detencion.run()

  def write():
    while runing == True:
      #sleep(10)
      line = ser.read(14)
      if line:
        print line
        file.write(line)
    itinerancia = Thread(target=write)

  def openPort(port='COM1', baudrate=1920, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1):
    try:
      global ser
      global file
      port = varCOM.get()
      baudrate = int(varBaudRate.get())
      bytesize = int(varDataBits.get())
      stopbits = int(varStopBits.get()) 
      ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baudrate, bytesize=bytesize, parity=parity, stopbits=stopbits)
      file = open("lecture.txt", "a")
      file.write("-- INICIO PROGRAMA --\n")

      itinerancia.run()
      #while runing == True:
      #  line = ser.read(14)
      #  if line:
      #    print line
      #    file.write(line)
      file.write("\n-- FIN DEL PROGRAMA --\n")
      file.close()
    except serial.SerialException:
        print 'No se pudo abrir el puerto'
    return

  def ejecutar():
    detener = Button(master, text="Detener", command=detencionRun)
    detener.grid(row=3, column=0)

    t = Thread(target=openPort)
    t.run()

    ejecutar = Button(master, text="Ejecutar", command=ejecutar)
    ejecutar.grid(row=3, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  root = Tk()
  app = App(root)
  root.mainloop()
```

The application freezes in the while loop. 
[image: The app freezed]
Sorry for my bad English and coding (I'm new on Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try multithreading your app and putting the polling and file writing in other threads, or you can try parceling out the port reads and file writes in to smaller chunks inside a larger program loop so that processing large chunks of data won't completely block the execution of the program.  Just keep in mind that if you do try to parcel it out, you'll probably want to set things up with a read and write buffer so that you don't accidentally dump or overwrite data in memory before you've fully written or processed it.